# Geany: debugger not available although plugins installed

Tags: ide, geany

I am running Geany 1.32 on Ubuntu 18.04. I am experiencing an issue where after installing the plugins, no debuggers are available under Tools > Plugin Manager (I am specifically looking for a C debugger) . Below are the commands which I ran when installing Geany and the plugins:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins-common
$ sudo apt install geany-plugins
```

What could be causing the debugger plugin to not be available?

Comment: Which debugger are you expecting?

Comment: The C debugger.

Comment: Geany do not provide _C debugger_, but a [debugger plugin](https://plugins.geany.org/debugger.html)

Comment: It indicates that the plugin supports GDB, which can be used to debug c code.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer to the same question, and am disappointed that there's no response.

All I've been able to find elsewhere is a reference [to this changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geany-plugins/1.32+dfsg-3) which says:

```
geany-plugins (1.32+dfsg-3) unstable; urgency=medium

  * [67b34ed] Disable webkit-using plugins: markdown, webhelper
    webkitgtk-3.0 is not to be used as it is deprecated, but the port to
    webkit2gtk-4.0 isn't ready yet.

 -- Chow Loong Jin <email address hidden>  Thu, 11 Jan 2018 03:17:55 +0800
```

The debug plugin seems to be one of the ones affected by this, so apparently it hasn't been working for almost two-and-a-half years.

I haven't been able to find anywhere yet that gives any hint of when (or if) this will ever be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the C debugger visible, you need to install **libvte-dev**.
Once you install **libvte-dev** with Geany closed you get the Debug Tab on next time you run Geany. You must have gdb installed.

**sudo apt-get install gdb libvte-dev**

Comment: Don't forget to add gdb

Comment: Just edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some Geany plugins where excluded because the relied on old libraries that contained bugs, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geany-plugins/+bug/1768412).

In newer versions, the debugger is included again because it updated its dependencies. You can use [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egeany-dev/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to have the excluded plugins in older Ubuntu, too:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geany-dev/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get install geany-plugin-debugger
```